# Navigate into elements with JQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-traversing

I have this elements hierarchy :

```
<div>
   <div>
      <input id="abc" .../>
   </div>
   <div>
      <span />
   </div>
</div>
```

How can I access to span element via input whom I know id please ?

I think I have to use

```
$("#abc").parent().parent()...
```

...but after please ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
$("#abc").parent().next().children('span')
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gRfnb/21/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vYfzg/1/)**

```
var spanElement = $('#abc').parent().next().find('span');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#abc").parent().next().children('span')
```